# HTML Number doesn't work in javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Why string below cannot display HTML symbols inside `<script>`?

```
<?php
$user_currency_symbol = '&#122;&#322;';

echo "
<script>$user_currency_symbol</script>
";
```

Comment: What does your HTML reveal? You also didn't include any errors messages.

Comment: The resulting `<script>&#122;&#322;</script>` simply isn't valid JavaScript and wouldn't do anything. Why not just `echo "&#122;&#322;"`?

Answer (score 3):

HTML `<script>` element content is not-parsed-as-HTML<sup>1</sup> and does *not* allow normal HTML escape characters; thus, there is no meaning attached to `&#0122;` or `&#0322;` and they *appear literally* in the resulting JavaScript program text.

Use the appropriate *JavaScript string* escape instead. In this case the escape happens as part of JavaScript parsing, not HTML parsing.

```
<script>prompt("\u0122\u0322")</script>
```

<sup>1</sup>The details can be found in the grammar allowed for the [text content of a script element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) and can be summarized as "no HTML parsing occurs between the start and end <script> tags". However, pay attention to notes about the ruckus a contained "<!--" or "<script>" can cause..